# Saber el nombre de alumnos que están matriculados a todas las asignaturas

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Muy buenas, me gustaría saber cómo decirle que me diga los alumnos que están matriculados en TODAS las asignaturas, ese TODAS me tiene loco, estoy muy desesperado ya con esta preguntita.

De momento tengo esto:

```
SELECT alumne.nom
   FROM alumne INNER JOIN notes ON alumne.nexp = notes.nexp INNER JOIN assignatura ON notes.codasig = assignatura.codasig
   WHERE COUNT (assignatura.codasig) IN (SELECT COUNT (assignatura.codasig) FROM assignatura);
```

[image: Diseño de las tablas.]

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si pones las relaciones mejor.

Comment: También es importante por un lado que copies y pegues la consulta en lugar de poner una imagen, y que expliques que falla en ella.

Comment: Okey, para la próxima ya lo sé. Pero el problema es que no sé como hacer para que me diga TODOS los alumnos que están matriculador en TODAS las asignaturas, no es que no me vaya, es que no sé hacerla.

Comment: No solo para la próxima, puedes hacerlo en esta, [editas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/138979/edit) la pregunta y añades la consulta en texto

Comment: Ya está. Pero, ¿sabéis dónde está el problema? O si podéis decirme como se hace os lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Yo ahora mismo no puedo, luego si tengo tiempo le echo un vistazo.Un consejo para que puedas recibir ayuda mas fácil. Si puedes generar el esquema y algun dato de prueba en [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) y lo compartes, es mucho mas fácil que alguien entre y pueda probar directamente ahi para darte una solucion :)

Comment: No estoy muy seguro de lo que te voy a contestar porque como dicen algunos compañeros faltan datos en el diagrama para ver exactamente como resolverlo, pero aún así, lo que yo veo es que no hay una relación directa entre alumnos y adignaturas. La relacion entre las dos entidades es mediante notas, así que como mucho podrás ver las asignaturas de un alumno que tenga notas en ellas. Las asignaturas en las que el alumno no tenga notas no hay manera de relacionarlas con el alumno, es decir, no puedes saber si está matriculado o no a menos que tenga una nota en esa asignatura.

Comment: El problema aca es ese todos. las consultas te van a devolver lo que le digas, pero para probar el todos, lo mejor que podes hacer es darnos un ejemplo que podamos probar, porque no es tan trivial como hacer un join lo que buscas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No ibas mal encaminado, una solución podría ser esta

```
SELECT NOM
FROM NOTES INNER JOIN ALUMNE ON ( NOTES.NEXP=ALUMNE.NEXP)
GROUP BY NOTES.NEXP
HAVING COUNT(NOTES.NEXP)=( Select DISTINCT COUNT(CODASIG)
                           FROM ASSIGNATURA
                         )
```

Saludos

Comment: Gracias, lo corregimos en clase y la solución era esa, muchas gracias!

Comment: Me alegra oir eso Alex. Si ha resuelto tu problema no olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta para que se de la consulta por solucionada.

Comment: @Alex si esta respuesta ayudó a solucionar el problema de tu pregunta, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) haciendo click en el **✔️**, que está bajo las flechas de votación, a la izquierda de la misma (no se te descuenta nada por eso -todo lo contrario, ambos se benefician).

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto:

```
SELECT N.NEXP, A.NOM
FROM INSTITUT.ALUMNE A
RIGHT JOIN INSTITUT.NOTE N
    ON N.NEXP = A.NEXP
GROUP BY N.NEXP, A.NOM
```

No necesitas acceder a la tabla de Asignaturas si no vas a mostrar su nombre, ya que la Primary Key de la tabla intermedia es un conjunto de la de alumnos y la de asignaturas.

He usado el Group By para que no salgan repetidos en ningún caso. 
Al no tener esa base de datos no puedo probarlo, pero creo que te puede funcionar.

Comment: ¡Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Si te ha servido de ayuda, marca la respuesta como como buena :)

Comment: Buenas, Alejandro. La Qy planteada es erronea. Principalmente porque en ningún momento revisas que los alumnos estén matriculados en todas las asignaturas del centro. Te invito a echarle un ojo a mi respuesta.